# Load data from firebase in chunks

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, query-optimization

I have to load approx 5000 user data from firebase realtime database and show it to user in list so i need to implement loadmore functionality below is the code which load all the data

```
mDatabase.child(getString(R.string.users)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        usersList.clear();
        if(newPost!=null){

            // perform data manupulation
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        loading.dismiss();
    }
});
```

I have tried limittofirst and limittolast but its not sort out my problem as i need data in-betweeen after first load and also like to optimize dowload as well so that data wont get downloaded again and again i.e first 100 then first 200 and so on its dowloaded the same data again and consume the firebase bandwidth

Can you please tell me how to implement loadmore functionality in firebase realtime database in effective way?

Comment: Thanks@ creativecreatorormaybenot but i have check Cloud firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data but didn't get any info.Can you please share anything including anythirdparty library so that i can achieve my goal

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Accessing the Firebase Database works the same from Cloud Functions as it does from a Node.js client. There are no additional query capabilities there.

Comment: @user3732629 It sounds like you want to implement [pagination on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%5bandroid%5d%20pagination). Unless you can share what you tried and what was hard, it's going to be a bit broad to help you beyond what's already done in the questions I linked.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen i will try and update here if anythings works